# OBJ file is not getting exported properly

Tags: obj

I am trying to export a blen file as an obj. It is not getting exported properly. Am I missing anything here...

Attached are the pics
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are you opening the obj in? This looks like the application tries to triangulate ngons and fails.

Comment: In the exporter window check in Geometry>>Triangulate Faces

Comment: Thanks, it worked